# Partition of Listbox?

Tags: silverlight, listbox, silverlight-2.0, multiple-columns

Is it possible to partition of list box into several columns. If yes which property is used for that in Silver light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the MSDN documentation to [customizing ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(VS.95).aspx)

Also see [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Using a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093(VS.95).aspx)